# URL Rewrite Rule .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I need to create a rewrite rule for the following URL and I need to pass "id" and widget with the GET superglobal

http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=1866&widget=Dangerfield

Is it possible to only use the widget parameter & value in the re-written URL and still be just as functional, and if so, how?

Comment: Please post your current code from your .htaccess

Comment: do you rely on id in order to display your pages? then you need to have id in there also.

Comment: This question has been answered about 6348275623498 times before...

Answer (score 0):

Simple you'd add this to your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /index.php?id=$1&widget=$2 [L]
```

The original URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php?id=1866&widget=Dangerfield
```

The rewritten URL:

```
http://www.domain.com/1866/Dangerfield.html
```

This is search engine friendly, your pages would be easily SEOed in search engines with a .html extension. It's better than having parameter at the end of the url which isn't seo friendly.

Answer (score 0):

Steering assistance subdomain

The original URL:

```
http://domain.com/index.php?cat=cats&id=12&url=stackoverflow
```

The rewritten URL:

```
http://cats.domain.com/12/stackoverflow.html
```

Code to rewrite rule for above in `.htaccess`